# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object (google maps api function)

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, drupal

Getting the PHP notice 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object' from the following function that uses Google maps API to find the distance between two postcodes (specifically the 'return' line of the code is triggering the notice)

```
function findTheDistanceBetween($postcode_from, $postcode_to){

    // tidy up spaces
    $postcode_from      = str_replace(" ", "+", $postcode_from);
    $postcode_to        = str_replace(" ", "+", $postcode_to);

    // get JSON back from Google
    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$postcode_from&destinations=$postcode_to&sensor=false&units=metric");

    // convert to a normal array
    $php_array = json_decode($json);

    // extract output and return it
    return $php_array->rows["0"]->elements["0"]->distance->value;

}
```

This is part of a drupal site if that makes any difference.

I am also getting another notice from the same return line: 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in findTheDistanceBetween()

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: the `$php_array` is not what you expect. It does not contain `$php_array->rows["0"]->elements["0"]->distance->value`. Try `print_r($php_array);`

Comment: The error message should include the line number where the error occured. That is useful information, please provide it.

Comment: Your code is not very 'robust': it should treat the case when $json contains an error

Comment: thanks - just edited the post to highlight the line - it's the 'return' statement that is triggering the notice.

Comment: your code works when I run it `findTheDistanceBetween(3020, 3000);` is `1280451`. In your case, there must be an error returned by google.

Comment: The error messages are quite self explanatory. The first thing you should do is, just like @PaulH mentioned in his first comment, dump the contents of `$php_array` to see what it _actually_ contains.

Comment: Btw... since you're sending data as url parameters, I think it's better to use `urlencode()` on the params instead of your own `str_replace()`.

Comment: Dumping the array gave `stdClassObject([destination_addresses] => Array(
 [0] => CharltonRise,
 Ludlow,
 ShropshireSY81ND,
 UK
) [origin_addresses] => Array(
 [0] => BridgeSt,
 Banbury,
 OxfordshireOX165PN,
 UK
) [rows] => Array(
 [0] => stdClassObject([elements] => Array(
  [0] => stdClassObject([distance] => stdClassObject([text] => 130km[value] => 129780) [duration] => stdClassObject([text] => 1hour43mins[value] => 6194) [status] => OK)
 ))
) [status] => OK)`

Comment: Just to add - it is working for me, it's just returning the notice which is confusing me.

Comment: It's working! I was on the wrong foot then :-(  I cannot reproduce the Notice. Maybe use `rows[0]->elements[0]` instead of `rows["0"]->elements["0"]`

Comment: If it's *working*, Maybe the function is called twice: one with Notice, once working.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a way to include error handling

```
$maps_object = json_decode($json);
if (isset($maps_object->status)) {
    if ($maps_object->status == "OK") {
        // extract output and return it
        return $maps_object->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value;
    } else { 
        // adapt content to your error handling
        return 'json status: ' . $maps_object->status; 
    } 
} else {
    return 'could not obtain json';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing/surrounding the *Noticed* statement like this for your debug:

```
if (isset($maps_object->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value)) {
    return $maps_object->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value;
} else {
    $error = "Error in: ". __FUNCTION__ ."() file:". __FILE__ ." line:". __LINE__ ."<br>\njson: $json<br>\n";
    echo $error;
    return $error;
}
```